# Acesso de Leitura para Users

Tags: login, microsoft-azure

Estou tendo dificuldades em criar usuários com acesso somente de leitura no SQL Azure.

Ele me retorna a mensagem:

> "The server principal "****" is not able to access the database "****" under the current security context."
>   Cannot open the user default database.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

De uma olhada na documentação sobre [Azure SQL Database - Controle de Acesso - Autorização](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-control-access#authorization). La explica os tipos de permissionamento possíveis com Azure SQL Database.

Para ver as instruções SQL para realizar alterações nessas permissões, veja essa documentação sobre [SQL - Segurança - Permissões em Bancos de Dados](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine).

Aplique permissões em nível de servidor a logons e a usuários de permissões no nível de banco de dados com as instruções GRANT, REVOKE e DENY . Por exemplo:

```
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::RecursosHumanos.Empregados TO Alessandra;
REVOKE SELECT ON OBJECT::RecursosHumanos.Empregados TO Alessandra;
```

Veja aqui vários [exemplos de como recurpar informações de permissões](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine#span-data-ttu-id79f3f-1500a-nameexamplesa-exemplosspanspan-classsxs-lookupspan-data-stu-id79f3f-1500a-nameexamplesa-examplesspanspan).